# Format Text With Spaces Between Lines

Tags: text-formatting

I am copying text from a pdf, and when I paste it into a text editor it comes out like this:

[image]

The text does not extend to the right margin but looks like a column, and there's a space between the lines. I'd like the text to extend to the right margin and no spaces between lines. I can format this manually, but it's very time consuming. Is there a program which will allow me to automate this?

Comment: What do you mean by _right margin_? What margin? Text files have no margin. If it's text, why post an image here? Do you mean every other line is an empty line? Or is it your text editor displaying the text like that? What text editor doesn't use a fixed-width font like that?

Comment: I posted an image to illustrate exactly what the text looks like. I don't know the answers to your other questions.

Comment: @user8547 If you want text to be displayed as-is on SE put it in a code block.

Comment: @BroSlow Outside the block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep .` removes all blank lines. You can pipe the result into [`fmt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fmt) to reformat the text to a width of your choice. If you have the text in the X clipboard, `xsel -b` will get it from there.

```
xsel -b | grep . | fmt -w 80 >reformatted.txt
```

If you don't want line breaks at all, you can replace newlines by spaces, but add a newline at the end.

```
xsel -b | grep . | tr '\n' ' '; echo
```

The output won't be very good, because according to your image, hyphens are lost, so “vul-/gar” comes out as “vul gar”, “Thanks-/giving” as “Thanksgiving”, etc.

`grep .` collapses all paragraphs into one. You can avoid this only if there is some way in which paragraphs are marked in your text. If there is a single blank lines between lines of the same paragraph and at least two blank lines between paragraph, you can remove line breaks and preserve paragraph breaks like this:

```
awk 'length {if (previous < NR-2) print ""; previous = NR; print}'
```

You can try running [`pdftotext`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext) on the PDF directly. This won't reformat the text and may or may not include the blank lines (it depends how the PDF was made).

Comment: This worked well, only I used "fmt -w 999" instead of "fmt -w 999999999" because the latter came back as an "invalid width."

Answer (score 1):

You can do it:

```
awk -v RS=$'\n\n' -v ORS=" " '1 { print; }' file | fold
```

Comment: Where do I put the name of the input text file in that command?

Comment: @user8547 Hard to believe that this question is serious. You replace `file` with the real name of the file.

Comment: This works. But I prefer Gilles answer because his commands give me the option to set the width or get rid of line breaks.

Comment: @user8547 I usually prefer Gilles's answers, too... But you can set the width with `fold`, too: `--spaces --width=`. The `awk` part deletes all line breaks.